# Permission error when uploading video to youtube channel through api interface

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We want to upload videos to our youtube channel through api interface

But when authorizing, although it shows that we have obtained permission, when uploading, it prompts "this app is blocked"

Please help us see how to solve this problem，thank you

[app blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulWl3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code you're using.  If it's blocked, you probably need to contact Google and inquire why your app is blocked or whether you're not using the right credentials.